# Splitting html tag with sub tag in c#

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Is there an elegant way to separate out a sentence that is in an HTML node and has an HTML tag itself?
The html document might look something like this:

```html
<body> 

<div> 

Our lovely pet&#39;s name is  <span style='color:blue;font-weight:bold'>Snoopy</span> and he is a pilot too. His best friend is a bird.</div> 

</div> 

</body>
```

Users shall be able to look in my document for search keys, like “pilot”. Then the corresponding sentence shall be high lighted, but the sentences (before and) after shall stay the same. So this might look like this:

```html
<body> 

<div> 

<span style='color:red;font-weight:normal'>Our lovely pet&#39;s name is  </span><span style='color:blue;font-weight:bold'>Snoopy</span><span style='color:red;font-weight:normal'> and he is a pilot too</span>. His best friend is a bird. 

</div> 

</body>
```

Comment: Slightly related, for marking text there exists the [`<mark>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/mark) element

Comment: You tagged HAP (fine, that is what you need). Did you already use it on this issue? What were the problems?

Comment: Yes, I have tried HAP. The problem is that if there is no tag in my sentence, I can do node.innerHtml = node.innerHtml.replace(OldSentence, NewSentence), but with the tag the innerText is different than the innerHtml and the OldSentence is not found. I can try finding the begining of the sentence in a child or grandchild node and insert the start of the tag or the end. But this is not the most elegant way.